# UITextView height based on content text in UiTableView Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, textview

I try several time to make textview inside tableview cell to be sized height based on text inside textview. I tried the following with no luck:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TnCityFeedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CityFeedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.FeedMainText.text = [[self.FeedArray valueForKey:@"FEED_MAIN_TEXT"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    CGSize size = [cell.FeedMainText systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:cell.FeedMainText.contentSize];
    CGRect frame = cell.FeedMainText.frame;
    frame.size.height = size.height;
    cell.FeedMainText.frame = frame;

    return cell;
}
```

I hope to find some way to solve this

Thanks
:)

Answer (score 0):

If adding the following two lines to ViewDidLoad do not do the trick,

```
  self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 44.0;
  self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Try adding the following two methods to your class. I'm subtracting 20 from my table view's frame to add margins; you may not want to do that.

```
- (CGFloat) getHeightForTextView: (UITextView *)theTextView {
     float height = [self textViewHeightForRowAtIndexPath:nil theTextView:theTextView];
     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width-20, height);
     theTextView.frame = frame;
     return [self textViewHeightForRowAtIndexPath:nil theTextView:theTextView];
}

- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath theTextView: (UITextView *)theTextView {
     CGSize size = [theTextView  sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width-20, FLT_MAX)];
     return size.height;
}
```

And use them like this in your controller. I'm only returning the height for my "problem" textview.

```
(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   }
   return [self getHeightForTextView:problem];
}
```

Comment: Did you remove the 4 lines where you set FeedMainText frame? And did you verify the getHeightForTextView method is executed?

Comment: Yes I do but the problem is how can I put my textview in replace of "problem" in "heightForRowAtIndexPath"? it should be cell.FeedMainText

Comment: Within "heightForRowAtIndexPath" you can create a UITextView and set its text property to
" [[self.FeedArray valueForKey:@"FEED_MAIN_TEXT"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];", then return "getHeightForTextview" for the new UITextView.
Unfortunately at the time "heightForRowAtIndexPath" is called the cell may not be yet created so you cannot use "getCellForRowAtIndexPath:".

Comment: Habeeli, if this answer worked for you please up vote or mark it as answer.